# How can we model independent noise for every output dimension of a multi-output GP in GPflow?

Tags: gpflow

Say I have a problem having *D* outputs with isotopic data, I would like to use independent noise for each output dimension of a multi-output GP model (Intrinsic Coregionalisation Model) in gpflow, which is the most general case like:

[image: a busy cat]

I have seen some example of using multi-output GPs in GPflow, like [this notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/GPflow/GPflow/blob/develop/doc/source/notebooks/advanced/coregionalisation.ipynb) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57361754/multi-output-gp-with-multi-inputs)

However, it seems for the `GPR` model class in gpflow, the likelihood variance ($\Sigma$) is still one number instead of *D* numbers even if a product kernel (i.e. Kernel * Coregionalization) is specified.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you can augment `X` with a column that designates for each data point (row) which output it relates to (the column is specified by the `active_dims` keyword argument to the `Coregion` kernel; note that it is zero-based indexing), you can augment `Y` with a column to specify different likelihoods (the `SwitchedLikelihood` is hard-coded to require the index to be in the *last* column of `Y`) - there is an example (Demo 2) in the [varying noise notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/GPflow/GPflow/blob/develop/doc/source/notebooks/advanced/varying_noise.ipynb#Demo-2:-grouped-noise-variances) in the GPflow tutorials. You just have to combine the two, use a Coregion kernel and a SwitchedLikelihood, and augment both X and Y with the same column indicating outputs!

However, as plain GPR only works with a Gaussian likelihood, the GPR model has been hard-coded for a Gaussian likelihood. It would certainly be *possible* to write a version of it that can deal with different Gaussian likelihoods for the different outputs, but you would have to do it all manually in the `_build_likelihood` method of a new model (incorporating the stitching code from the `SwitchedLikelihood`).

It would be much easier to simply use a `VGP` model that can handle any likelihood - for Gaussian likelihoods the optimisation problem is very simple and should be easy to optimise using `ScipyOptimizer`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just wondering why use VGP in the notebook, as I am trying to use the standard GPR in gpflow, however when I manually specify the GPR's likelihood attribute from Gaussian() to SwitchedLikelihood, it told me  'SwitchedLikelihood' object has no attribute 'variance' when I call compute_log_likelihood() for testing

Comment: @Will plain GPR *only* works with a Gaussian likelihood, and the `GPR` model is hard-coded for a Gaussian likelihood - you could certainly rewrite it to work with different Gaussian likelihoods for the different outputs, but you would have to do it all manually in the `_build_likelihood` method.